# Loop outputs keep the last output without renewing the output

Tags: python-3.x

I have a loop, with many variables as outputs in the loop...some variables are keeping the output of the passing before, instead of giving me a new output. Even if the output could not be found, it should return None, and not the repeat the last output.

```
for line in csv_urls:
   website = line[0]
   print(website)
   try:
      f = urllib.request.urlopen(line[0])
      a = f.read().decode('utf-8')
      cnpj_final = "Not Found"
      cnpj = None
      cnpj = re.findall(r"\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}\-\d{2}", a)
      if cnpj != []:
           x = cnpj
           x = set(x)
           seen_cnpj = set()
           cnpj_final = []
           for item in x:
              if item not in seen_cnpj:
                  seen_cnpj.add(item)
                  cnpj_final.append(item)
              else:
                  cnpj_final = None
       else:
           cnpj_final = "Not Found"
       print("CNPJ:", cnpj_final, '\n')
   except:
         pass
         cnpj_final = None

>>> https://www.medsam.com.br
    CNPJ: ['20.104.619/0001-53']

>>> https://www.clamarrocaplus.com.br
    CNPJ: ['20.104.619/0001-53']

>>> https://www.anisboutique.com.br
    CNPJ: ['31.410.120/0001-90']
```

Once, it could not find the CNPJ for the 2nd website, it kept the 1st website. How do I stop that from happening? The 3rd CNPJ was found and output was renewed ok.